# Change header's font type on click anywhere in XtraGrid view

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a windows forms application and I am using XtraGrid suit and I am with the following problem:

I need to change the appearance of the header and the cell at the time the User clicks the mouse right or left button.

I'm already using `CustomRowCellEdit` events to display an image in the cell.
`RowCellStyle` to change the background of the cell
`gridView1_RowCellStyle` and `gridView1_CustomDrawCell` to draw a check box in the header to select all rows.

Could someone help me with this problem please.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I asked to Devexpress team support then they answered this "To change a column caption font, use this column's AppearanceHeader property. To change font settings to all cells in the column, use the AppearanceCell property. If you wish to change font settings for a specific cell, handle the GridView.RowCellStyle event. In this event handler, specify the e.Appearance.Font property in a manner similar to the one you used to change a cell background."
This worked well.
Thanks for the attention